# Run command as different user (from command line)

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation

How to run a command (i.e. wget command downloading a file or a batch file) as other user from command line:

- being logged in as local Windows SYSTEM user
- not having to specify a password for user

It is possible on linux:

```
runuser -l oracle
```

Is it possible on Windows?

What I am trying to acheive - I want to automate changing registry settings of
local Windows users from command line without logging in as this user,
in *NO* domain environment.

Comment: So, you dont want to use something like RunAs ... ?

Comment: `runas /user:oracle command` for instance to start cmd.exe as user oracle `runas /user:oracle cmd.exe`

Comment: `runas` asks for password. I need to make it work like linux `runuser`, which does not ask for user's password. So I don't want to use `runas`.

Comment: well, just as `runuser` cannot be run without having correct setup, so can runas not be used. it is like `sudo` etc. you need to have the privilege to perform a task. Read more about UAC on windows and you'll see it is all about security.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but not from a batch script. schtasks.exe allows configuring a task to use an S4U batch logon, but it requires the user's password to create the task, and the user must have the batch logon right, which standard users aren't granted by default.

Comment: Eryksun, what if user's password change? Scheduled task would not run?

Comment: It seems that it is not possible on Windows, because Microsoft designed it that way. On Linux it is possible. There is some "hope" in using undocumented Windows API mentioned here [link](https://serverfault.com/a/17004)